# Simple Apache Rewrite Rule Giving Unwanted 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:`RewriteRule ^/uk/(.*)$ http://www.hostname.uk/$1 [R,L]`

which rewrites the url from:

- `http://www.hostname.uk/uk/home`
  to
- `http://www.hostname.uk/home`

However instead of seeing the content at `http://www.hostname.uk/uk/home` with the shorter address you get a blank 404 page instead. Why is this? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The rule you have is redirecting from `/uk/home` to `/home`, but you don't have anything in place to rewrite in the other direction. This is what you need. You should also use a 301 redirect (permanent) which I did here. You were using a 302 (temporary - the default). You also don't need to specify the `http://www.hostname.uk` when it's not changing.

```
RewriteRule ^/uk/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /uk/$1 [L]
```

I am assuming you are doing this in your main Apache configuration. If it's in your `.htaccess` then it will need changing.

Comment: This rule is included in a virtual host file. Unfortunately this does not appear to work as I am still receiving a 404 not found at www.hostname.uk/home.

Comment: I've been looking at this for serveral hours and as far as I can tell it should work. Am I missing something here? RewriteCond?

Comment: Is there a file at `/uk/home`?

Comment: The web page files are located at /sites/uk, so I attempted the following `RewriteRule ^/uk/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sites/uk/$1 [L]` however this gives me a **403 Forbidden** page and an additional 404 error.